# New URL's not showing up in google search results

Tags: magento-1.8, search

Recently we changed the URL structure. We removed parent category path from the URL's.

For ex: www.example.com/display-cabinets/display-counters has been changed to www.example.com/display-counters

We generated a new sitemap and submitted it to Google webmaster tools.

The problem is, In Google results, we can't able to see the exact URL (www.example.com/display-counters) when we search for it.

Instead Google displays the old cache "www.example.com › Display Cabinets" like these in search results. But when we click, it redirects to the correct page (www.example.com/display-counters).

Please check the below image. You will get an idea of what I was mentioning.

[image]

We need the new URL (www.example.com/display-counters) to be shown in Google results. Can you please suggest what we can do for this.

Looking forward for the response.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the old url are still valid you should create 301's redirect (or Canonical). See https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/XCvryr14mtY
2. Create/log in to your google webmaster tool account
3. You will have to wait until Google re-indexes your website, which normally take up to few weeks to complete. Once that happens, you will see the updated URLs on Google.

Also see [How to change sitelinks in Google Webmaster Tools](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/7AqlDU9uYWM)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually the old url's are not valid now. 301 redirect is already applied to all url's. It's already more than a month, but still google is showing the same URL but it leads to the correct page. I mean it shows "www.example.com › Display Cabinets" but it leads to the correct page "www.example.com/display-counters".

Comment: The problem is Google indexed the new url, but it is showing the previous indexed cache in the result. We need "www.example.com/display-counters" instead of "www.example.com › Display Cabinets".